# Confusion over the current density outside of current carrying wire

Tags: electromagnetism

If a want to calculate the current density outside of a current carrying wire with current $I$ then the law 
$I= \int_A\vec J\cdot d\vec A$ so it is not zero, it must be smaller than the current density in the inside because the area is larger. But there is no electric field outside so $\vec J = \sigma\vec E$ gives zero.

My question is, if the current density outside is zero or not? And why?

Comment: Have a look http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elecur.html#c1  and http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current density $\vec J$ is definitely zero outside a current carrying wire, but not for the reasons you mentioned. It is true $\vec J = \sigma \vec E$ where $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the material. Outside the current carrying wire, it is $\sigma = 0$ that causes $\vec J = 0$. The electric field outside a current carrying wire is *not* zero because it must satisfy the boundary condition that the parallel component $E^{||}$ must be continuous.